# Template Template Parameters - Invalid Explicitly Specified Argument

Tags: c++, template-templates

I am just learning how to work with template template parameters and am having trouble invoking a function.

Compiler Error:
candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'Container'

My purpose in using the template template approach is to have a very generic composite class that can handle any container type.

For illustration purposes, I am working with Shapes. So I have a ShapeComposite, PolyLine, and a ShapeFactory.

PolyLine extends ShapeComposite and ShapeComposite is where the generic container will live. Can you please help me understand why I am running into this compiler error?

Shape.hpp

```
class Shape
{
public:
    // just an abstract interface for concrete shapes 
};
```

ShapeComposite.hpp

```
template<typename T,template<typename S, typename Alloc> class Container, typename TAlloc = std::allocator<T>>
class ShapeComposite : public Shape
{
private:
    Container<T, TAlloc> shapes;

public:
    ShapeComposite();
    ~ShapeComposite() override = default;

    void addShape(const std::shared_ptr<Shape>& shape);
```

ShapeComposite.cpp

```
template<typename T, template<typename S, typename Alloc> class Container, typename TAlloc>
ShapeComposite<T, Container, TAlloc>::ShapeComposite() : shapes{}
{
    // default ctor
}

template<typename T, template<typename S, typename Alloc> class Container, typename TAlloc>
void ShapeComposite<T, Container, TAlloc>::addShape(const std::shared_ptr<Shape>& shape)
{
    shapes.push_back(shape);
}
```

PolyLine.hpp

```
template<typename T, template<typename S, typename Alloc> class Container, typename TAlloc = std::allocator<T>>
class PolyLine : ShapeComposite<T, Container, TAlloc>
{
public:
    PolyLine();
    ~PolyLine() override = default;
};
```

PolyLine.cpp

```
template<typename T, template<typename S, typename Alloc> class Container, typename TAlloc>
PolyLine<T, Container, TAlloc>::PolyLine() : ShapeComposite<Point, Container, TAlloc>()
{
    // default ctor
}
```

ShapeFactory.hpp

```
class ShapeFactory
{
public:
    ShapeFactory() = default;
    virtual ~ShapeFactory() = default;

    virtual Point createStartPoint();
    virtual Point createEndPoint();
    virtual Line createLine() final;

    virtual Point createPoint() = 0;

    template<typename T = Point, template<typename S, typename Alloc> 
    class Container,  typename TAlloc = std::allocator<T>>
    PolyLine<T, Container> createPolyLine();
};
```

ShapeFactory.cpp

```
Point ShapeFactory::createStartPoint()
{
    return createPoint();
}

Point ShapeFactory::createEndPoint()
{
    return createPoint();
}

// Template method
Line ShapeFactory::createLine()
{
    Point startPoint = createStartPoint();
    Point endPoint = createEndPoint();
    return Line{startPoint, endPoint};
}

template<typename T, template<typename S, typename Alloc> class Container, typename TAlloc>
PolyLine<T, Container> ShapeFactory::createPolyLine()
{
    PolyLine<T, Container> polyLine ;
    int numLines = 0;

    std::cout << "How many lines would you like to create? ";
    std::cin >> numLines;

    for (int i = 0; i < numLines; ++i)
    {
        Line line = createLine();
        polyLine.addShape(line);
    }
}
```

ConsoleShapeFactory (just a concrete factory but creating a PolyLine is implemented in the base class)

```
class ConsoleShapeFactory : public ShapeFactory
{
public:
    ConsoleShapeFactory();
    ~ConsoleShapeFactory() override = default;

    // Function Overrides
    Point createPoint() override;
};
```

Attempt to create a PolyLine via the ShapeFacotry:

```
int main()
{
    ConsoleShapeFactory factory;
    factory.createPolyLine<std::list<Point>>()();
}
```

Comment: Please post complete code that generates a mentioned error.

Comment: So what did you pass to `Container`? `std::list<Point>`?

Comment: @Evg I added more details as you requested.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes, I did std::list<Point> and also tried std::vector<Point>

Comment: Then it should be just `typename Container`. What you wrote is for receiving e.g. `std::list` without arguments.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am not entirely sure what you mean by this. Do you mind providing an example?

Are you saying that I should modify this:
    template<typename T = Point, template<typename S, typename Alloc> class 
    Container,  typename TAlloc = std::allocator<T>>
    PolyLine<T, Container> createPolyLine();

to this:
    template<typename T = Point, typename Container,  typename TAlloc = 
    std::allocator<T>>
    PolyLine<T, Container> createPolyLine();

Comment: You have two options. If you want to pass e.g. `std::list<T>` (with `<...>`), then the respective template parameter must be `typename Container` and not the whole `template <...> class Container` thing. OR you can keep it as is, and pass `std::list` without `<T>` (you have to add it when using `Container` in that template).

Comment: please read about [mcve]. Most of the code you posted is irrelevant to the issue

Comment: Just trying to respond as requested by the first comment.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're confusing templates and types. `std::list` is a (class) template. `std::list<Point>` is an instantiated class template, and therefore a class, and a type.

I can't figure out what you want. Do you want to allow `Factory.createPolyLine<std::list<FooBar::Point>>()();` as well? If so, you need to define waht properties a point-like class should have.

It also seems you're defining templates in .cpp files. That can't work; the template body has to be available at the point of instantiation. I.e. `Factory.createPolyLine<std::list<Point>>()();` requires not just the declaration, but the whole definition of `createPolyLine`

Comment: Defining templates in .cpp files can work when you #include it in the .hpp. I realize I didn’t copy that into the code above, however, so I’ll clarify that.